# How to Insert to MySQL with php and echo it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm really new to PHP and need some help.

I want to build a forum where you can upload posts and pictures.

Now, I need help with the connection between my code and my MySQL database.

I'm using MySQL with the folowing table:

main table: "posts"

1. post_data = it's  an POST request from the user.
2. username = from another main table: users
3. user_id = from another main table: users
4. post_id = Automatic .

I want to post the data that I get from the user and I don't really know what the problem is.

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php

session_start();
$MySQLdb = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=forum", "root", "");
$MySQLdb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 if(isset($_POST['msg'])){

     $post   = $_POST['msg'];

     $cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("SELECT post_data FROM posts WHERE post=:posts_data");
     $cursor->execute( array(":post_data"=>$post) );
 }
$cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post) value (:post_data)");
$cursor->execute(array(":post_data"=>$post));?>
```

and this is the HTML code for "msg" (the post input):

```
div class="input-group">
                <input id="msg" type="text" method="POST" class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Write your message here...">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><button id="send_post">Send</button></span>
            </div>
```

This is the error that I get:

> Notice: Undefined variable: post in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\main.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'post' in 'field list' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\main.php:15 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\main.php(15): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\main.php on line 15

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `WHERE post=:posts_data` You have no column named `post` in your table description.

Comment: For your information, you can't *"insert to phpMyAdmin"*, this is a **tool** used to manage MySQL databases, like *MySQL Workbench*

Comment: You also use `:posts_data` in your query but use `:post_data` in your execute. That will be the next error you get.

Comment: Your $post variable is empty

Comment: Sorry you are INSERTING into POST column instead of  POST_DATA column which happens to be your column name in the POSTS TBL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which of the lines is Line 15? is it the `$cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post) value (:post_data)");`

Because if it so then you might want to find a way of SETTING you `$post` variable. Take a look at your code, you are setting `$post` inside the `if(){} statement` and so when it tries to execute the below lines:

```
$cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post) value (:post_data)");
$cursor->execute(array(":post_data"=>$post));?>
```

Your `$post` variable is empty.

Comment: I did that and got this error: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'post' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\main.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\main.php(15): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\main.php on line 15

Comment: As the exception is saying, the post column is not part of the table, you have to crosscheck

Answer (score 0):

Your html is all wrong.

```
        <input id="msg" type="text" method="POST" class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Write your message here...">
```

The method is an attribute on form tag, not input.

```
<form action="/youraction" method="POST" />
<input id="msg" type="text" method="POST" class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Write your message here...">
</form>
```

PHP fails because there's no `$_POST['msg']` set

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps method your html form is get or ...

Change 
`$_POST['msg'];` 
to
`$_REQUEST['msg'];`

```
<?php

session_start();
$MySQLdb = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=forum", "root", "");
$MySQLdb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $post   ="";
 if(isset($_REQUEST['msg'])){

     $post   = $_REQUEST['msg'];

     $cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("SELECT post_data FROM posts WHERE post=:posts_data");
     $cursor->execute( array(":post_data"=>$post) );
 }
$cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post) value (:post_data)");
$cursor->execute(array(":post_data"=>$post));?>
```

Comment: I did that and got : Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'post' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\main.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\main.php(15): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\main.php on line 15

Answer (score 0):

"INSERT INTO posts (post) value (:post_data)" must be changed to **"INSERT INTO posts (post_data) value (:post_data)"**.

Please be aware, that there might come new MySQL errors depending on your table definition and the defined constraints.